# 500 OOPS: vsftpd: not configured for standalone, must be started from inetd

Tags: macports, ftp-server

i'm have a problem when intall vsftpd using mac port,when i wanna to start service of vsftp with

`sudo /opt/local/sbin/vsftpd`

i have the error like this

`500 OOPS: vsftpd: not configured for standalone, must be started from inetd`.

anyone can suggest me how must i can do it?

this is my vsftpd.config

```
# Example config file /opt/local/etc/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Beware - allowed by default if you comment this out).
anonymous_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
#local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
#write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
#local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/opt/local/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /opt/local/var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/opt/local/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/opt/local/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# When "listen" directive is enabled, vsftpd runs in standalone mode and
# listens on IPv4 sockets. This directive cannot be used in conjunction
# with the listen_ipv6 directive.
listen=YES
#
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. To listen on IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets, you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration files.
# Make sure, that one of the listen options is commented !!
#listen_ipv6=YES
#
# Name of pam module
pam_service_name=ftpd`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my solution problem , just rename vsftpd.config to vsftpd.conf , i don't know why that is not read vsftpd.config when i rename to vsftpd.conf that work in my local mac.

Comment: This is due to the file permission of vsftpd.conf, when you renamed it the user name changed to your current user which can access the vsftpd.conf file.

Answer (score 3):

Uncomment
listen=NO
to
listen=YES
in vsftpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

I believe the build of vsftpd was not configured to be started the way you are trying to do. You'll either have to install a build that is configured to start from the command line, or start it instead from inetd, which starts services during initial boot. Look for a startup script in /etc/init.d. In some distros, there is a script that runs to manage what services start during boot. I don't have a MAC, so I can't give you more guidance, sorry.

Comment: yeah, i think so but i don't know to start from xinet maybe someone can be help me alot

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a vsftpd well configured and it was working, however after installing cloudpanel it stopeed working. After reinstalling it and rebooting it still didn't work.

The problem was a process that was still alive at port 21.

```
sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:21`
sudo systemctl restart vsftpd
```

Killing that process worked for me and afther running the next command I can see it working again.

```
sudo systemctl status vsftpd
```